# spell checker: ignore CamelCaseWords

Tags: firefox, spell-checking

Is there a way to get the spell checker to properly check camel cased words? "ThisIsSpelledRightly" would be marked as spelled correctly, but "ThisIsNottSpeledRihgt" would be flagged?

I use Xubuntu and firefox.

I tried asking this over on superuser, but it got ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the [Firefox] spell checker to properly check camel cased words?

Not directly.  You would have to manually put spaces in the camel case word.  After Firefox checks the spelling, you then delete the spaces.  Right clicking on the camel case word and turning off the spell checker for that word will remove the red underline under the camel case word.

camelCaseWord -> camel Case Word [for spell checking] -> camelCaseWord